# Site https Redirect not working, also need .php exclusion

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

My objective is apply an EV SSL to redirect using htaccess all the .HTML pages on my site to https, however, I created the site in DW CS6 and the majority (over 1,000) of the pages are .php and cannot be https, since they are all syndicated content feeds from EMC, VMware, etc. I also built dozens of deep links for all the .php pages.

Extensive searching through all the pages here provided what seemed like the best and most logical solution.

Step 1. Redirect the entire site first to https

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then

Step 2.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The problem is I never got to test step 2 because step 1 did not work, the site remains http://www.erpsaa.com/ but of course if you simply add the "s"  https://www.erpsaa.com/ which was my objective, it works perfectly, and if you hit any of the deep link .php pages, it also works and goes directly back to http. However, that then kicks the entire site back to http. I have what I believe to be a partial solution for step 2.The parent.php links are effected, because with an entire site redirect (manual) the 4 .php parents are destroyed, SSL gives the "mixed content issue". I could set it up so that none of the links are the parent .php, but make all the links deep links and achieve the same purpose. However, I am still left with the problem of what I found here to be confirmed by more than one person was the exact way to redirect one's entire site from http to https. Perhaps in my case overall, is a 301 code for the entire site better, with the bandaid for the .php pages, whose deep links always force https to http.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match `php` extension using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable (that is used for matching domains only).

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule !\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I now have the second solution, but still am unable to fix the initial problem of simply redirecting my entire website from http to https. The code I posted above is not working, yet it seems correct.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you want entire site on `https` then what is purpose of `!\.php$` condition?

Comment: @anubhava-The .php pages are partially coded to syndicate content from our partners e.g, EMC or Juniper. To explain would take too much text, but if you my home page: https://www.erpsaa.com/ or the Contact Us page (or any html after starting off https) it works, But, go to any .PHP page under the Solution menu, for example http://tinyurl.com/koxe435 and the .php works perfect, it comes out of secure https and goes to http. The problem is once the site is pulled from https to an http page, it fails to go back to the pages which should be https, namely all the .html pages. Thank you.

Comment: Ok can you try `RewriteRule` as this: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]` and test in a new browser

Comment: Thank you.  It now does exactly what I want and it's a good thing I kept your .php code just in case one I was able to get the entire site to redirect, it would not effect the .,php.  Perfect! This eas the final and it's up and running:

Comment: @anubhavaThank you.  It now does exactly what I want and it's a good thing I kept your .php code just in case one I was able to get the entire site to redirect, it would not effect the .,php.  Perfect! This eas the final and it's up and running:

Comment: Glad to know it all worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.